# Is there any way to incorporate gnuplot's charts into winform

Tags: c#, winforms, gnuplot

Hi
For my console application I've been using gnuplot to draw charts. However now I'm creating GUI for my application and in my opinion Gnuplot chart window opening outside of form will be look ugly. So I was wondering if there is any way to somehow incorporate external gnuplot chart window into winform

Answer (score 0):

The most primitive way of achieving that would be to make gnuplot output a the graph as a PNG file (via the [set output](http://www.gnuplot.info/faq/faq.html#SECTION00052000000000000000) option) and then loading that into your winform once the operation completes. You'll want the [System.Diagnostics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) namespace for launching gnuplot.

Comment: Could you please clarify how to output the graph as a png. Everything i have tried thus far has failed. Someone has suggested using named pipes but it seems a little over my head. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10583932/unable-to-save-gnuplot-png-from-within-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use something else like [zedgraph](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zedgraph/) or many other possibilities in C# to display plots in your GUI. Like that, you can even achieve some interaction with the plot itself, which would be very hard to realize with gnuplot.

Answer (score 0):

Novikov has the right of it, but there ARE interactive chart types in GNUplot, and all plots, while viewed in the GNUplot viewer window, are interactive.

Perhaps the best solution is to do both.  Display the static .png by default, but offer a button to launch the GNUplot window for interactivity.

Answer (score 0):

Gnuplot can take a command file that configures a plot and output the plot to a GIF, PNG or various other formats.  You can then display the output in an image viewer.

Comment: Evening, every time ive tried to run Gnuplot from within c#, i always get two windows appear, the plot and a black window similar to a command prompt. How do you recommend interfacing c# with gnuplot? Ive tried the process class but it doesnt seem to perform as i had hoped. any pointers would be appreciated.