# Unable to save Gnuplot png from within c#

Tags: c#-4.0, gnuplot

im trying to open gnuplot from within c# and get it to save a png of a chart. There are 2 issues im having

1) both a black commandline box for gnuplot and the actual plot appear. I would like both of these to not appear.

2) After setting the terminal to png and plotting sin(x) it doesnt actually save the file. These same commands work within gnuplot though.

Any tips would be appreciated

Thanks

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string Pgm = @"C:\Program Files\gnuplot\bin\gnuplot.exe";
        Process extPro = new Process();
        extPro.StartInfo.FileName = Pgm;
        extPro.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        extPro.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        extPro.Start();

        StreamWriter gnupStWr = extPro.StandardInput;

        gnupStWr.WriteLine("Set terminal png");
        gnupStWr.WriteLine(@"set output 'c:\Users\FrazMan\Desktop\sinxplot2.png'");
        gnupStWr.WriteLine("plot sin(x)");
        gnupStWr.WriteLine("set terminal wxt enhanced");
        gnupStWr.WriteLine("set output");
        gnupStWr.Flush();
    }
```

[image: This is what's happening in image form]

Comment: I don't know any C#, but I assume that gnupStWr.WriteLine(...) appends a newline to the end of the string it is writing?  If it doesn't, you can add trailing semicolons inside your strings or newlines ...

Comment: As far as im aware yes it does. gnupStWr.Write() would be the equivalent without creating a new line after the string.

Comment: Also, I feel like I've seen somewhere that on windows you should pipe the commands to wgnuplot or pgnuplot (I don't remember which) -- I'm not really sure why and I don't have a windows system to test any of this on...

Comment: Hi, i changed the line string Pgm = @"C:\Program Files\gnuplot\bin\gnuplot.exe" to both wgnuplot.exe and wgnuplot_pipes.exe but neither works.Both just start the application thats all. Any other ideas? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm out of ideas -- hopefully someone who understands piping gnuplot commands on windows will come along.

Comment: Np, thank you very much for your help anyway, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems to me that you could have a problem with your script for the GNUPLOT

Try something simpler

I think the following script should work

```
gnupStWr.WriteLine("set terminal png");
gnupStWr.WriteLine(@"set output 'c:\Users\FrazMan\Desktop\sinxplot2.png'");
gnupStWr.WriteLine("plot sin(x)");
```

Try to avoid capital letters for `"set terminal png"`

I hope it will help you